# Any way to set "type" attribute on input box from an App script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm currently designing a Google Site that will use a lot of Apps Scripts.

This webpage will be used as well from iOS devices and so I'm trying to make it easier for users to enter the correct information by using the HTML5 Input types that are available (specifically input type='email' and type='number').  (As seen here for example: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/)

As far as I can see in the documentation, there's no way to do that, but wanted to ask to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible using UiApp input elements.

Comment: Figured as much. Thanks for the confirmation.